# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component - indicates a memory leak

Tags: reactjs

In Login component I called login function to expect asynchronous behavior.

```
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    
    if (usernameRef.current.value === "" || passwordRef.current.value === "") {
        return setError('username or password field should not be empty')
    }

    setError('')
    setLoading(true)
    try {
        const res = await login(usernameRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
        localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.access_token)
        history.push("/")
        setLoading(false)
    } catch {
        setError('Could not login')
        setLoading(false)
    }
}
```

In authContext, I wrote this two right below:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/me", {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
            },
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res.statusText)
            setCurrentUser(res.data)
            setLoading(false)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    
    return unsubscribe
}, [])

const login = async (username, password) => {
    const details = {
        "username": username,
        "password": password
    }
    let formBody = [];
    for (let property in details) {
        let encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
        let encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
        formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
    }
    formBody = formBody.join("&");

    return await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/login", formBody, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
        }
    })
}
```

Is there any problem on fetching? Whenever I login, it does login successfully but arise the error that indicates To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Comment: The thing to remember is that there is nothing for which to update the state if your component hasn't mounted yet: state _of what_? There is no UI element. Think of state as the data that you need while your UI element is visible to the user. Anything else is props that should get passed down by the parent to either bootstrap the state, or data that gets loaded it _after_ the component's loaded in your UI.

Comment: I couldn't understand. Sorry, I used context to avoid props drilling. Does login func cause any error?

Comment: Try moving `setLoading(false)` to before the `history.push('/')` in your login component. Now you are trying to set the loading state of the login component when it is no longer available because you have already pushed to a new page I think.

Comment: yes, it works and not getting errors but can you tell me why `history.push('/')` isn't working?

Comment: Because once you push the history to a new page the login component unmounts. Then after that you are trying to set the loading state of the login component but the login component has already unmounted. That is why you are getting the error `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component` because essentially you are trying to perform `setLoading(false)` to a component that is already gone because you have already pushed to a new page. So you just have to perform `setLoading(false)` before you push to a new page.